# laravel 5 middleware /check activation status before postlogin()

Tags: php, authentication, laravel-5

I need some help, I created a field "activation_key", which is assigned to each user after registration. How to check now, when a user tries to login if he's activated (activation key =null) or not (showing an error message). This check process should be done BEFORE laravel postLogin() runs. I think I must use middleware before, but no idea about the logic itself, how to tell laravel if check was "true" or "false". All in all I'm not sure, how to get this done...

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class BeforeMiddleware
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
         if (Auth::user()->activation_key) {
        // then redirect home cause they're not activated
        //return redirect('home');
        //not active ;()
        dd("not active seems ugly :I");
    }

    dd("you're active yay");

    }
}
```

routes:

```
// Authentication routes...
Route::get('auth/login', '***');
Route::post('auth/login', 'Auth\AuthController@postLogin');
Route::get('auth/logout', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogout');
```

All the best;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track.

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    // if they have a key...
    if (Auth::user()->activation_key) {
        // then redirect home cause they're not activated
        return redirect('home');
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

The above works, however this part reads poorly: `!Auth::user()->activation_key`

You could abstract that to a method on your User model:

```
public function isNotActivated()
{
    return $this->activation_key ? true : false;
}
```

then your Middleware can read:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    // // if they have a key...
    if (Auth::user()->isNotActivated()) {
        return redirect('home');
    }

    return $next($request);
 }
```

EDIT:

To register the Middleware for every request, add it your `$middleware` array in `kernal.php`

```
protected $middleware = [
    \App\Http\Middleware\Activation::class,
];
```

or for specific routes in your app:

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    // ...
    'activation' => \App\Http\Middleware\Activation::class,

];
```

and then reference that middleware in your `routes.php`:

```
Route::get('users/profile', ['middleware' => 'activation', function () {
    //
}]);
```

See: http://laravel.com/docs/master/middleware#registering-middleware

Comment: If I use your first code block, did I need to telll laravel to use this middleware or should I just put this file into the middleware folder and it will get called each time BEFORE a request is handled by the login module?

Comment: @peke_peke i updated my answer with information on registering mdidleware -- which is the next step

Comment: Thanks, but how to reference middleware using this style? Take a look to first post, I posted my routes, *** mark the part I mean.

Comment: `Authentication routes... Route::get('auth/login', ['middleware'=>'activation']);

Comment: added route, now laravel says `Class 'App\Http\Middleware\Auth' not found`.

Comment: I needed to add includes, now it works, but as I see now (I need to fill databse with some entries) this is done BEFORE the login, all in all, how can I access `Auth::user()` without logging my self into, laravel can't know the username at this stage of login process or am I wrong?

Comment: Without logging in you can't know which User is accessing your application.

Answer (score 1):

Auth::user will return null until authentication is complete, and I don't want to allow the user to login just to be able to use Auth::user. So, I made the following mods to dtj's answer.

This is my middleware

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if(User::isNotActivated($request->email)) {
        return redirect('home');
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

This is my UserRepository

```
public static function isNotActivated($email)
{
    $user = User::findUserByLogin($email);

    return $user->activated ? false : true;
}
```

And, this is my User model

```
public static function findUserByLogin($email)
{
    return static::where('email', $email)->first();
}
```

That way, I use the email passed through the post, find it in the DB, check for activated column, and return with result.